# Interval time of reading from wifi card in Android

Tags: android, wifi

I would like to ask about WifiReceiver class. 
I'm using the below custom class to read rssi values,

This class is called each 500 millisecond, but it returns data (not empty string) each 4 seconds approximately.
My application needs a new rssi values each 1 second ... how can I do this?

```
public class WirelessNetworks 
{
        private static WifiManager wifi;
        private static List<ScanResult> results;
        private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
        private static String AllReadings;
        static WifiReceiver  receiverWifi;


        public static String FindSpesificNetworks() 
        {
            wifi.startScan();
            return AllReadings;
        }


        public static void Initial(Context context)
        {
            wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            receiverWifi=new WifiReceiver();
            context.registerReceiver(receiverWifi, 
                    new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        }



        public static class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {
                AllReadings = new String();

                results=wifi.getScanResults();

                int size = results.size()-1;

                while (size >= 0) 
                {
                    String MAC = results.get(size).BSSID;
                    String RSSI = String.valueOf(results.get(size).level);
                    // Save MAC and RSSI as string in allreadings    
                    size--;
                }

            }           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra delay is due to the processing time... The total time is the sum of your delay and the delay due to the processing.

Comment: But in Samsung note 2 10.1 it takes 4 seconds while it takes only 1.2 seconds in Galaxy s2. it is not possible that this difference in delay is due to processing time.

Comment: It is possible. Because in different phones the delay is different.. Its not only the CPU processing time.. Its based on the total memory available to process.. Wifi card type.. Wifi receiver strength n load of the phone

Comment: you can compare between them and see which is logically takes a little time from this link:  http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=5677&idPhone2=3621

Comment: Does your Note 2 and S2 have same load. I mean currently running applications and background processes ?